# Proxy to HTTPs site

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, https

I use a rotating IP proxy server with Google Chrome's [Proxy SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif) extension. The problem is that if I go to the http://icanhazip.com/ (note: HTTP protocol), my IP changes on every page reload. However, going to the https://icanhazip.com, my IP changes only after a while.

In addition, I have noticed few things:

1. If I "Close idle sockets" on chrome://net-internals/#sockets -- the IP changes.
2. If I clear Chrome's browsing data, on page reload I am asked to re-auth again and after that the IP changes.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: have you tried shift-refresh, / hard refresh, so it doesn't refresh from the cache?

Comment: @barlop I have. Doesn't work :(